# Anyone Know a Way to Inherit the Parent of an Extended Class?

Tags: less

**Background:**

Im working on a framework that has browser classes applied to the HTML element.
Im trying to apply a cross browser fix (for safari5) whenever I extend to a mixin.

**Example Markup:**

```
<html class="safari5">
    <div class="child"></div>
</html>
```

**LESS:**

```
.mixin{
  content:"cool style mixin that breaks on safari";
}

.safari5{
  .fix{content:"hacks safari5's bullshit and semi-fixes cool style mixin"!important;}
}

.child{
  &:extend(.mixin);
  &:extend(.fix);
}
/*
```

**Expected CSS Output:**

```
.mixin,
.child {
  content: "cool style that breaks on safari";
}

.safari5 .fix, 
.safari5 .child{
  content:"hacks safari5's bullshit and semi-fixes cool style mixin"!important;
}
*/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [`extend all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-). E.g.:

```
.mixin {
    1: 1;
}

.safari5 {
    .fix {2: 2}
}

.child {
    &:extend(.mixin, .fix all);
}
```

Comment: Leaving a note just for anybody else who had the same confusion as me. When using `&:extend(.mixin, .fix all);` the `all` keyword applies only to `.fix` and not to all extended selectors.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know "all" caught ancestors as well as descendents!